# Asyncronous Rachet tree: How user movability is handled is the Rachet tree being recreated?

Tags: keys, key-exchange

As I have read the latest state of art in group key agreement is the [Asyncronous Rachet Tree](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/666).

But in applications like IRC that exists high user movability (users join in ans leave the room). Is there a mechanism that updates/refreshes the key when users join or leave the chat room to the ART key agreement?

So far in the [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/666.pdf) the only refresh is mentioned when a user changes its key.